# Blogger widget is not seen in layout

Tags: html, widget, blogger

I'm kinda new to Blogger gadget/widget making and I'm curious why I can't see the widget I created. I was able to see the section but no widget was made. Does anyone know why?

Thanks!

Code:

```
            <b:section id='Navigator-Bar' class='NavBar' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
                <b:widget type='Navbar' id='Navbar1' locked='yes' title='Navigation' mobile='yes'>
                    <b:includable id='main'>
                        <data:content/>
                    </b:includable>
                </b:widget>
            </b:section>
```

Here's what I see in Layout page.

[image: Widget not has not appeared]

Comment: Probably you can see your widget in preview and not in the layout.

Comment: I added HTML elements inside the widget too and it won't work.

Comment: Change `maxwidgets='3' showaddelement='yes'`.